# Visual realtime CSS specificity calculator?

Tags: css, firebug, firefox-addon

I have seen some online css specificity calculators but you have to upload the css files and do some manual work for it to do its work.

Is there a visual one like maybe a Firebug extension where when you click or hover over an element, it calculates it right there in real time?

Comment: Ive alaways jsut used the CSS pane in firebug to see what the cascade looks like then just override as necessary. Its a little bit harder on the brain than the tool you speak of but it works for me :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can [MRI](http://www.westciv.com/mri/):

> MRI is a free cross browser tool that
>   lets you test selectors with any web
>   page. Selectors, particularly complex
>   ones can be difficult to get exactly
>   right - MRI lets you experiment with
>   them on any web page (local or online,
>   static or dynamic).

Comment: MRI is no longer free.